karate.Runner execution with multiple tags and features
I am trying to run karate suite with multiple tags and features but then none of feature scenarios get executed. Below is the code:
import com.dell.karate.ReportportalHook;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import com.intuit.karate.RunnerOptions;

class TestRunnerParallel {

@Test
void testParallel() throws IOException {

    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("@test1");
    tags.add("@test2");
    List<String> features = new ArrayList<String>();
    features.add("testSuite1");

    RunnerOptions options = RunnerOptions.fromAnnotationAndSystemProperties(features, tags, getClass());
    Results results = Runner.parallel(options.getTags(),
            options.getFeatures(),
            options.getName(),
            Collections.singletonList(new ReportportalHook()),
            1,
            null);
}

}
But when only one tag, like below code, it executes fine. Note: when I execute one tag per execution it works fine. I am unsure what the issue is ?
import com.dell.karate.ReportportalHook;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import com.intuit.karate.RunnerOptions;

class TestRunnerParallel {

@Test
void testParallel() throws IOException {

    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("@test1");
    List<String>  features = null;

    RunnerOptions options = RunnerOptions.fromAnnotationAndSystemProperties(features, tags, getClass());
    Results results = Runner.parallel(options.getTags(),
            options.getFeatures(),
            options.getName(),
            Collections.singletonList(new ReportportalHook()),
            1,
            null);
}

}

Tag1.feature
Feature: Test Feature1

  @run_first
  Scenario: Scenario1
    * print 'Scenario1'

  @run_second
  Scenario: Scenario2
    * print 'Scenario2'


Tag2.feature
Feature: Test Feature2

  @run_third
  Scenario: Scenario3
  * print 'Scenario3'

TagTestParallel.java
public class TagTestParallel {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/tests/")
                  .tags("@run_second,@run_third")
                .parallel(0);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}


I have added Tag1.feature and Tag2.feature under src/test/java in a package called com.tests. This should work. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to have a similar solution but with RunnerOptions.fromAnnotationAndSystemProperties and Runner.parallel?

No idea with RunnerOptions.
